# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent where parent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have two models setup, User and Post. Post has a `belongsTo` setup of user and User has a `hasMany` setup for posts.

When getting all my posts, I want to make sure the user isn't banned. Banned is an int in the database in a column called `ban` and I want to make sure it's equal to 0. I originally looped through the posts, checked to make sure user wasn't banned and then pushed it to an array and passed that array to the view which was working fine. However, I now want to enable paginate and it's broken because I'm not passing in the eloquent object.

Here is my eloquent right now:

```
$posts = Post::where('status', '>', 1)->orderBy('published_date', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: by which model and by which field should the user be checked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `whereHas()`

```
$posts = Post::where('status', '>', 1)->whereHas('user', function($q) {
    $q->where('ban', 0);
})->orderBy('published_date', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

I assume, you have `user` relation on `User` model from `Post` model.